# How to center text (responsive) in image using css/html

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make responsive text inside an image? I would like to do it without using media queries. I already tried this [Horizontal centering text over image via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209764/horizontal-centering-text-over-image-via-css) but it does not work.

The problem (pic. down) is when reaching small screen values, the text goes outside the image and it does not resize it. With media queries I could do it just by changing the size of the text, but is not any other way to do it?

[image: Text outside image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper-pig">
     <center><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/4axzhhujp/schwein.png" style="width: 70%; height=auto;"/></center>
      <div class="pig-text" >
           <span style="color:white;" >9563</span>
       </div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.wrapper-pig{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: yellow;
   position: relative;
   box-sizing: border-box;

}

.pig-text{
    font-size: 160%;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 40%;
    top: 40%;
}
```

Please, any help?

I prepared a fiddle to show the problem better: [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4exojyc/)

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated since the medieval ages.

Comment: So you also want the text to shrink?

Comment: Yes, it should shrink as well

Answer (score 3):

You can make this to center perfectly:

```
.pig-text{
  font-size: 160%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Here, the text doesn't shrink.

Comment: Thx, this is part of my solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use a responsive font size, check out this here

https://jsfiddle.net/f11y74ms/

The hint comes from

[Responsive font size according to window width, is it possible with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836955/responsive-font-size-according-to-window-width-is-it-possible-with-css)

The commands are `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, so the smallest viewpoint is taken as a reference.

Comment: Thx, this helps me. My final solution is a combination of your answer and from @Marcos Perez

Answer (score 0):

You can try what RobertStettler has said.

You can use viewport value instead of ems, pxs or pts.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
>
> 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

```
.schwein-text{
    font-size: 4vw;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 40%;
    top: 40%;
}
```

**[Working Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/f11y74ms/1/)**